# Offline web push notifications

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to create offline push notifications in browser? More specifically, users have access only to given site and can't access any external sources, so services like Firebase won't suffice.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably look into Service Workers and making your app "progressive", working offline. Then it's only a matter of triggering the notification via the Notification API. Here's [Google's guide](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/display-a-notification) on that.
Usually the tricky part is triggering Push notification events from a server to client, but since it's not in your concerns, should be pretty straightforward to follow the above tutorial.

Comment: is using websockets more efficient?

Comment: I've only dealt with socket.io for this purpose, which under the hood utilizes websockets, among other techniques. It works well, but you could also check out Firebase for 'serverless' solution. They provide notification service called "Cloud Messaging". Many other options, I guess.